# comparing a string to an input form user. java

Tags: java

Here is a piece  of the code

```
    System.out.println("How would you describe your lifestyle? Sedentary, Somewhat Active, Active, Highly Active?");
    String lifestyle = keyboard.next(); 
 if (lifestyle.equalsIgnoreCase("Somewhat Active"))
 {
  System.out.println("ok");
 }
 else
 {
  System.out.println("not ok")
 }
```

no matter what I type I cannot get an "ok" response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Scanner#next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) will always return the next *token*, which will just be "Somewhat". Use [`keyboard.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) instead.

Comment: but how "Somewhat".equalsIgnoreCase("Somewhat Active") will it return true?

Comment: @JunedAhsan No, the two strings aren't equal. "someWHAT eQuAL" would be acceptable in such a comparison, however. The OP is currently using `next()` which returns just "somewhat" which would of course not compare as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `nextLine()` as suggested by hexafraction.

```
String lifestyle = keyboard.next(); //<-- input without space, Somewhat
String lifestyle = keyboard.nextLine(); //<-- input with spaces, Somewhat Active
```